# Storing data for a evil hangman program

Tags: java, data-structures, set

I have to write a hangman program, Only the "house" is evil and changes the word so the player (hopefully) loses.

I will create a set of all the words at the start of the game when they player chooses a letter i will create a set that matches the pattern, and continue creating the optimal subset.

for example

Assuming the user selects 3 letter words, and for this examples sake we will say there are only the following 3 letter words in the english language; Dog Fog And Fox Cat Not Bus

If the user Guesses "o" the program will compile a list of words with out "o" in them, I will sort this list in to sets one set would be "and" the other "bus" and an other "cat"

However I was wondering what the best method would be to store these sets.

Comment: I'm confused. So if the word changes, what happens to the letters already guessed correctly? Or do they change around positions for the new word?

Comment: What do you mean by have the logic sorted? In what way does the house change the word? Examples will help here. Lastly, the way you do these things will alter the ideal way in which to store the words.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://nifty.stanford.edu/2011/schwarz-evil-hangman/

Comment: Ah, that somewhat helps explain it templatetypedef, it sounds more or less like what OP's task is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a suggestion, think about what operation you need to efficiently support.  You will need to be able to take a word, map it to its word family, and from there to distribute the word into the collection of words matching that family.  For this, consider using something like a `Map` that will associate the word family (represented however you wish) with the collection of words matching that family.  You can represent the collection in many ways - as a `Set`, as a `List`, etc.  That way, you can easily take the string, convert it to a word family, and then map the word family to the set of all words in that family.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase what you are doing:

1. You have a set of words for a specified length.
2. Every time the user specifies a character, you want to remove from your current set all the words that have that character in it without emptying the set.

Optionally, to be even more evil:

1. If your set now is empty, you want to choose from your original set of words the largest subset of words that have the specified character at the same index.

Is this what you want to do?

If so, I would consider thinking about what you are going to be doing a lot.

Given a text file containing a large list of words. I would first form the list of sets of words, partitioned by character length.

Once you duplicate that set, you can start asking the user for specific characters. As the characters are provided, you have to remove the words in the set that contain that character.

So, as you can see, the naive approach for solving this would be to iterate through all the words in the set, and iterating through the characters to see if it contains the specified character.

A better way could be to bin the words by the characters that they contain. Good luck!

Comment: Be aware that *which* letters are stored is not the whole story; you have to track *where* they're stored as well.  If you precompute everything, this is going to use a *lot* of memory.